# Adding plugin support for a Windows Universal Application

Tags: .net, plugins, uwp

We know UWP applications run into a sandbox. But I would like to create some kind of "plugins" that would allow users to extend the functionality.

I imagine that just copying a bunch of assemblies into the application's folder won't work.

Is this even possible? How?

**EDIT:**
My plugin **should include code to be executed from the host**. My application (the host) supports loading common file formats, but with the use of a plugin, it would be able to allow users to import other extra formats. Currently, I'm loading assemblies from the application folder dynamically, looking for types that implement a custom `IImporter`, but in order for this to work, I have to manually add a static reference from the app project to the plugin, something that spoils the whole thing, because a plugin shouldn't require to rebuild the application.

Comment: Need to be explicit what kind of capability you need. If you are talking about accessing desktop components in general, you might be looking for broker runtime component.

Comment: The plugin will include code to be execute in-process. The application supports loading common file formats, but with some plugins, it will allow you to import other formats.

Answer (score 2):

Please, see the [Extend your app with services, extensions, and packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/extend-your-app-with-services-extensions-packages) chapter of docs.

Comment: My plugin should include code to be execute in-process. The application supports loading common file formats, but with some plugins, it would be able to allow users to import other extra formats. Does it mean I have to use an "Optional package"? Currently, I'm loading assemblies dynamically and looking for types that implement a custom IImporter interface

Comment: For what I understand, it's I cannot do it, because I would have to create a Option Package, and that is only available for C++ projects, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [app extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-an-extension) that are part of UWP APIs.

Comment: OK, but my main concern is about the kind of capabilities an App Extension has. In the sample, the extension only has content files, like XAML and some assets. Can App Extensions contain runnable code? I need my extension to contain classes that I want to discover in runtime to execute code from them.

Comment: TBH I've never worked with them but I believe that it should be possible.

Comment: Oh well, the docs say: "Applications cannot load code from extensions. If you need code execution, consider App Services". I need to load and execute code from a "third party" assembly. I hope someone could shed a bit of light on the topic :)